# Laravel empty array issue

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm having a problem when I submit form data and display it in another view, I get all the data except an array data type (`$mat_res`), here is my code:

View :

```
            var mat_codes = [];
            ...
            console.log(mat_codes);//displays an array with data
            $('#rest_form').on('submit', function(event) {
                //event.preventDefault();
                var form_data = $(this).serialize();                    
                var personnel = $('#personnel').val();
                var fonction = $('#fonction').val();
                var service = $('#service').val();
                var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
                var remarque = $('#remarque').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ route('Restituter.createRest') }}",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {
                        mat_codes: mat_codes,
                        personnel: personnel,
                        fonction: fonction,
                        remarque: remarque,
                        user_id: user_id
                    },                        
                    success: function(data) {
                        mat_codes = [];
                        $('#rest_form')[0].reset();
                    }
                });                   
            });
```

Controller :

```
public function createRest(Request $request) {
        ...
        $mat_res = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->mat_codes); $i++) {
                    if(($request->mat_codes)[$i] != "") {
                        Restitution::firstOrCreate(['mat_code' => ($request->mat_codes)[$i], 'personnel_id' => $personnel->id], ['mat_code' => ($request->mat_codes)[$i], 'personnel_id' => $personnel->id, 'num' => $num, 'mois' => date('m'), 'restitution_code' => $num . "/" . date('m') . "/" . date("Y"), 'user_id' => $request->user_id]);
                        Materiel::where('mat_code', '=', ($request->mat_codes)[$i])->update(array('mat_etat' => 2));
                        $mat_res[$i] = DB::table('Materiels')->join('Types', 'Materiels.type_id', '=', 'Types.type_id')->select('Types.type_designation', 'Materiels.mat_designation', 'Materiels.mat_description', 'Materiels.mat_ns', 'Materiels.note')->where('mat_code', ($request->mat_codes)[$i])->first();
                    }
                }
        ...
        return view('Restitution', compact('nom', 'fonction', 'imei1', 'imei2', 'remarque', 'rest_code'), ['mat_res' => $mat_res]);
}
```

Second view :

```
@foreach($mat_res as $mat_res)
 ...
    <td>{{$mat_res->type_designation}}</td>
 ...
@endforeach
```

Comment: Might be because `mat_codes` is not defined. @Sami Did you check the Javascript console?

Comment: `($request->mat_codes)[$i] != "")` could be simplified to `isset($request->mat_codes[$i])` just FYI. Are warnings/errors enabled? If so, are you getting any and if so, what are they? Have you tried to debug this by outputting the values to a log?

Comment: You are not assigining any variable call mat_codes on your ajax

Comment: @Sami Add `Error` messages or additional `Debugging` information.

Comment: When uncomment ```//event.preventDefault();``` and ```dd($mat_res);``` it's showing the array with all the data but when I comment ```event.preventDefault();``` and ```dd($mat_res);``` it's showing an empty array!

Comment: That proves @MD.JubairMizan right. You don't send all data in the ajax you are expecting in the controller. Also, this may not be related, your controller code is error prone. It's hard to read. I think there is an error in the `Restitution::firstOrCreate(...)`, you seem the interrupt the array buildup halfway.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey everything is working fine except for the empty array all the data is being inserted/updated in the MySQL tables and the console is not showing any error on both view and server sides!

Comment: If you `console.log(mat_codes)` inside the on submit function, you'll notice it's empty. Try to determine it's value inside the function, that is triggered by the submit event. If you comment the preventDefault() out, the jQuery ajax request isn't even triggered. That's why the expected values arrive at the controller without the ajax request. But it isn't with the ajax request. Functions are per definition self-isolating themselves from the rest of the code.

Comment: You missed add csrf token in AJAX method. Read doc. and add token.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey thank you very much, I solved the problem thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. Declare `mat_codes` inside the submit event:

```
    $('#rest_form').on('submit', function(event) {
        //event.preventDefault();
        var mat_codes = [];
        ... //this is where you populate mat_codes
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();  //you can drop this line, you don't use it                  
        var personnel = $('#personnel').val();
        var fonction = $('#fonction').val();
        var service = $('#service').val();
        var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
        var remarque = $('#remarque').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('Restituter.createRest') }}",
            method: "POST",
            data: { mat_codes, personnel, fonction, remarque, user_id },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data); //this is coming from you controller
                mat_codes = [];
                $('#rest_form')[0].reset();
            }
        });                   
    });
```

As a side note, as you are using ES2015, instead of `personnel: personnel`, just add `personal, fonction, ...` to the data object when key and value are the same. jQuery knows exactly what it means.